# Want tutorials for Windows Phone App Development (7.5/8)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8

Any useful link which contains proper Windows Phone App development tutorial ?
Do share please!

Thank You!

Comment: Did you try Google? I hear they're really good at finding stuff on the internet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- MSDN's [Beginning Windows Phone
  Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_basic_unit)
- Channel9's [Windows Phone 7 Development for Absolute
  Beginners](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners)

Comment: those will give a good foundation, but do note they are a bit dated and cover Windows Phone 7 - there are some significant changes and  new capabilities available with Windows Phone 8.

Comment: @JimO'Neil +1 Thanks for showing me the MS App Builder program, looks perfect for Windows Phone 8 app development joined the club :)

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft's App Builder program](http://build.windowsstore.com/build-windows-phone-apps-in-30-days) is specifically designed to take you from 0 to publishing in the Windows Phone (and Windows Store) in 30 days, so that's another good resource for curated content.

Comment: Only for US residents :(

Comment: I know the promotions like Keep the Cash are only for US residents, but are you saying the content is also inaccessible?

Comment: During signup, whenever I enter Phone Number this message appears:
"Looks like your phone number is more than 10 digits and may be from outside the United States. This offer is open only to US residents, age 18 or older."